# how do get input values from a bootstrap modal popoup in mvc 5 method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Please how do i get input values from a bootstrap modal popup from mvc 5 method, i am calling the method from a button click onclick event using this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-blue" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("SaveToDb")';return false;">

public void SaveToDb(AddressViewModel addrs)
    {
        var addressLine1 = addrs.AddressLine1;
        var addressLine2 = addrs.AddressLine2;
        var city = addrs.City;

    }
```

My Form:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
<!-- start: BOOTSTRAP EXTENDED MODALS -->

<div id="responsive" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760" style="display: none; top: 50px;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            &times;
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Address</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientId, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @ReadOnly = true } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressLine1, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressLine1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressLine1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressLine2, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressLine2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressLine2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-light-grey">
                Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Savetodb")';return false;">
                Save changes
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ends: BOOTSTRAP EXTENDED MODALS -->
```

i have a break point at SaveToDb method, but AddressViewModel object (addrs) is alway null. please any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Unclear what your expecting. Your not submitting a form or passing any values to the method.

Comment: I just included my modal popup form

Comment: You need a submit button to post the form. And the form needs an action attribute (use `Html.BeginForm()` so you html is generated correctly (either that of use jquery ajax to submit the form)

Comment: i have used Html.BeginForm(), but the value of addrs is still null!

Comment: Did you use a submit button (or ajax)? You current button has a `onclick` event that just does a redirect. It does not post any values.

Comment: This is what i used:  <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("SaveToDb")';return false;">

Comment: Yes, I know, and as I noted, that just does a redirect without passing any data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95415/discussion-between-uwakmfon-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: please how do i achieve that?

Comment: Wow It works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this is that your actual form is not posted, you are just redirecting here that's why your form data is not model binding properly. You could do a POST ajax call instead and pass your form data.